# How to Shim .this[]/indexing in C#?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sharepoint

I have an SPListItem and I use indexing (.this[]) to fetch a field value as shown below:

```
cellReportID.Text = item["ReportID"].ToString();
```

`item` is an instance of `SPListItem`
I need to write a test method for this and I am not sure how to shim this particular item["ReportID"] in my test method using Microsoft fakes.
Can anyone help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can get a new SPListItem index by calling SPList.Items.Add() -- you will need to have a reference to a list to create a new item.

Comment: I am  not adding a new item though. I am trying to fetch a value from SPListItem using that field name

Comment: I believe what you are looking for is SPListItem.FieldValues["ReportID"]

Comment: I think the answer will vary depending on the version of SharePoint on-premises vs online.  It also depends which SDK you are using to access SharePoint.  Are you using "Microsoft.SharePoint.dll" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms466906(v=office.14))  in an on-premises farm? are you using CSOM (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee541453(v=office.15)) or PnP? -- I think its either `.FieldValues[fieldName]` or `.Item[fieldName]`... put a breakpoint in there and see what you can see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following way of shimming works-

```
ShimSPListItem.AllInstances.ItemGetString = (INSTANCE, STRING) =>
{
    // Do something here
};
```